# How can I pick three random elements out of a dictionary in Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary

I am having a problem picking three random elements out of a dictionary.

My dictionary code:

```
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        var dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
    }
})
```

Comment: If your keys are integers, why not use an array?

Comment: To create an entry in your dictionary, the proper syntax is `namesOfPeople[2] = "peter"`

Comment: If you use Xcode 10 , use randomElement()

Comment: Let me guess: the problem is that this won't compile, right? The reason why was pointed out by @slickdaddy.

Comment: Your first step is to understand how to generate a random number in Swift. Suppose you needed to write a function to generate a random number between 0 and 9. Use Playground and write that. From there extrapolate into how to pick a random object from an array of 10 objects (0-9). From there load your firebase snapshot, create 10 objects from it's child nodes and stuff them into an array. Then use the function you developed to pick one of those objects. Or just use .randomElement on your dictionary or array if you have a later version of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array if keys are integers.

if you want to use a dictionary only then below mentioned code might be helpful for you

```
var namesOfPeople = [Int: String]()
namesOfPeople[1] = "jacob"
namesOfPeople[2] = "peter"
namesOfPeople[3] = "sam"

func makeList(n: Int) -> [Int] {
    print(namesOfPeopleCount)
    return (0..<n).map { _ in namesOfPeople.keys.randomElement()! }
}

let randomKeys = makeList(3)
```

You can try this for older version Of Swift where `randomElement()` is not available

```
let namesOfPeopleCount = namesOfPeople.count
func makeList(n: Int) -> [Int] {
  return (0..<n).map{ _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(namesOfPeopleCount)
}
```

Comment: Note that this might return the same name more that once.

Comment: Sorry @Satish but im using swift 4.1 not 4.2

Comment: Hi @Satish what if I have a dictionary from firebase like this please look at the updated question

Answer (score 0):

@Satish answer is fine but here's one which is a bit more complete and selects a random user from a list of users loaded from Firebase ensuring a user is only selected once.

We have have an app with two buttons

```
populateArray
selectRandomUser
```

and we have a UserClass to store our user data for each user.

```
class UserClass {
    var uid = ""
    var name = ""
    init(withSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        let dict = withSnapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        self.uid = withSnapshot.key
        self.name = dict["Name"] as! String
    }
}
```

and an array to store the users in

```
var userArray = [UserClass]()
```

When the populateArray button is clicked this code runs

```
func populateArray() {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let user = UserClass(withSnapshot: snap)
            self.userArray.append(user)
        }
        print("array populated")
    })
}
```

and then to select a random user use this code.

```
func selectRandomUser() {
    if let someUser = userArray.randomElement() {
        print("your random user: \(someUser.name)")
        let uid = someUser.uid
        if let index = userArray.index(where: { $0.uid == uid } ) {
            userArray.remove(at: index)
        }
    } else {
        print("no users remain")
    }
}
```

This code ensures the same user is not selected twice. Note that this is destructive to the array containing the users so if that's unwanted, make a copy of the array after it's populated and work with that.